# packets getting mixed in udp c# application

Tags: c#, udp

My UDP server application is receiving data from multiple clients

and in our server application we print all the messages recieved sent from different clients.

the issue is that the packets are getting mixed. this happens mostly when we have data packets
containing lot of data
Code sample is

udpServer.beginreceive(new asyncCallback(onUdbConnect), udpServer);

public void onUDPConnect(IAsyncResult a)
{

Comment: Well yes of course they're getting mixed, you're using UDP, UDP is **not** connection oriented, which means your server is simply just reading out any and all data sent to it no matter who/ what sent it and reading it in the order which it was received (large packets need to be split into multiple smaller ones, .NET does this for you). If you want to know who sent what you can either define your own protocol on top of UDP and require a client id to be sent along every packet or switch to TCP

Comment: Or use a existing higher level protocol built on top of UDP, like http3/QUIC.

Comment: Or use even higher level utilities/ frameworks built on top of higher level protocols, stuff like SignalR or gRPC (or a RPC library/ framework of your choice)